# How to delete columns that contain ONLY NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data.frame containing some columns with all NA values. How can I delete them from the data.frame?

Can I use the function,

```
na.omit(...)
```

specifying some additional arguments?

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible. Read the post [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame

Comment: can you post `head(data)`? Do you want to remove corresponding columns or rows?

Comment: @e4e5f4 I want to remove corresponding columns (all the values of the columns I want to remove are NA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
df[, colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)]
```

If the count of NAs in a column is equal to the number of rows, it must be entirely NA.

Or similarly

```
df[colSums(!is.na(df)) > 0]
```

Comment: How can I delete columns having more than a threshold of NA? or in Percentage (lets say above 50%)?

Comment: @lovedynasty Probably best to submit a separate question, assuming you haven't already since posting your comment. But anyway, you can always do something like `df[, colSums(is.na(df)) < nrow(df) * 0.5]` i.e. only keep columns with at least 50% non-blanks.

Comment: People working with a correlation matrix must use `df[, colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df) - 1]` since the diagonal is always `1`

Comment: Can use this with the dplyr (version 0.5.0) select_if function as well. 
`df %>% select_if(colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0)`

Comment: @MadScone it is giving me syntax error at "," for df[, colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)] and syntax error at "!" in df[colSums(!is.na(df)) > 0]. Am i missing something

Answer (score 99):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
df %>% select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)
```

**Update:** The `summarise_if()` function is superseded as of `dplyr 1.0`. Here are two other solutions that use the `where()` tidyselect function:

```
df %>% 
  select(
    where(
      ~sum(!is.na(.x)) > 0
    )
  )
```

```
df %>% 
  select(
    where(
      ~!all(is.na(.x))
    )
  )
```

Comment: At ~15k rows and ~5k columns, this is truly taking forever.

Comment: @EngrStudent  Was it faster with the accepted answer's solution?

Comment: It's been a number of years.  I don't remember.  DJV has a nice timing post below.

Comment: Here is the same answer on one line (more practical for copy-paste): `dplyr::select(dplyr::where(~sum(!is.na(.x)) > 0))`

Answer (score 42):

Another option is the `janitor` package:

```
df <- janitor::remove_empty(df, which = "cols")
```

https://github.com/sfirke/janitor

Comment: `janitor::remove_empty_cols()` is deprecated - use `df <- janitor::remove_empty(df, which = "cols")`

Comment: even `remove_empty()` works

Comment: I prefer this answer with @André.B's comment as the method in the selected answer above renames the columns to ```V1```, ```V2```, etc., but this method keeps the names of the columns as they are.

Answer (score 28):

It seeems like you want to remove **ONLY** columns with **ALL** `NA`s, leaving columns with some rows that do have `NA`s. I would do this (but I am sure there is an efficient vectorised soution:

```
#set seed for reproducibility
set.seed <- 103
df <- data.frame( id = 1:10 , nas = rep( NA , 10 ) , vals = sample( c( 1:3 , NA ) , 10 , repl = TRUE ) )
df
#      id nas vals
#   1   1  NA   NA
#   2   2  NA    2
#   3   3  NA    1
#   4   4  NA    2
#   5   5  NA    2
#   6   6  NA    3
#   7   7  NA    2
#   8   8  NA    3
#   9   9  NA    3
#   10 10  NA    2

#Use this command to remove columns that are entirely NA values, it will leave columns where only some values are NA
df[ , ! apply( df , 2 , function(x) all(is.na(x)) ) ]
#      id vals
#   1   1   NA
#   2   2    2
#   3   3    1
#   4   4    2
#   5   5    2
#   6   6    3
#   7   7    2
#   8   8    3
#   9   9    3
#   10 10    2
```

If you find yourself in the situation where you want to remove columns that have any `NA` values you can simply change the `all` command above to `any`.

Comment: The data.frame has two type of columns: one in whohc all values are numbers and the other in which all values are NA

Comment: So this will work then. It only removes columns were ALL values are `NA`.

Comment: Good solution. I would do `apply(is.na(df), 1, all)` though just because it's slightly neater and `is.na()` is used on all of `df` rather than one row at a time (show be a bit faster).

Comment: @MadScone good tip - does look neater. You should apply across columns not rows though.

Comment: @MadScone Edits are locked after 5 minutes on comments. I shouldn't worry, it's no biggie!! :-)

Comment: How can I delete columns having more than a threshold of NA? or in Percentage (lets say above 50%)?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon three years later.. are you still setting seeds like this? :}

Comment: I did this on a data table and it became a vector.  Nearly gave me a heart attack.  Had to convert to a frame.  It ran a lot faster.

Answer (score 24):

Another option with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), df)
```

NOTE: Data from @Simon O'Hanlon's post.

Answer (score 23):

An intuitive script: `dplyr::select_if(~!all(is.na(.)))`.  It literally keeps only not-all-elements-missing columns. (to delete all-element-missing columns).

```
> df <- data.frame( id = 1:10 , nas = rep( NA , 10 ) , vals = sample( c( 1:3 , NA ) , 10 , repl = TRUE ) )

> df %>% glimpse()
Observations: 10
Variables: 3
$ id   <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
$ nas  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ vals <int> NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, NA

> df %>% select_if(~!all(is.na(.))) 
   id vals
1   1   NA
2   2    1
3   3    1
4   4   NA
5   5    1
6   6    1
7   7    1
8   8    2
9   9    3
10 10   NA
```

Answer (score 18):

Because performance was really important for me, I benchmarked all the functions above.

NOTE: Data from @Simon O'Hanlon's post. Only with size 15000 instead of 10.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:15000,
                 nas = rep(NA, 15000), 
                 vals = sample(c(1:3, NA), 15000,
                               repl = TRUE))
df

MadSconeF1 <- function(x) x[, colSums(is.na(x)) != nrow(x)]

MadSconeF2 <- function(x) x[colSums(!is.na(x)) > 0]

BradCannell <- function(x) x %>% select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)

SimonOHanlon <- function(x) x[ , !apply(x, 2 ,function(y) all(is.na(y)))]

jsta <- function(x) janitor::remove_empty(x)

SiboJiang <- function(x) x %>% dplyr::select_if(~!all(is.na(.)))

akrun <- function(x) Filter(function(y) !all(is.na(y)), x)

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  "MadSconeF1" = {MadSconeF1(df)},
  "MadSconeF2" = {MadSconeF2(df)},
  "BradCannell" = {BradCannell(df)},
  "SimonOHanlon" = {SimonOHanlon(df)},
  "SiboJiang" = {SiboJiang(df)},
  "jsta" = {jsta(df)}, 
  "akrun" = {akrun(df)},
  times = 1000)

mbm
```

Results:

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval  cld
   MadSconeF1  154.5  178.35  257.9396  196.05  219.25   5001.0  1000 a   
   MadSconeF2  180.4  209.75  281.2541  226.40  251.05   6322.1  1000 a   
  BradCannell 2579.4 2884.90 3330.3700 3059.45 3379.30  33667.3  1000    d
 SimonOHanlon  511.0  565.00  943.3089  586.45  623.65 210338.4  1000  b  
    SiboJiang 2558.1 2853.05 3377.6702 3010.30 3310.00  89718.0  1000    d
         jsta 1544.8 1652.45 2031.5065 1706.05 1872.65  11594.9  1000   c 
        akrun   93.8  111.60  139.9482  121.90  135.45   3851.2  1000 a


autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

```
mbm %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample = time)) + 
  stat_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~expr, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the first iteration is a JIT compiled, so it has very poor, and not very characteristic, times. I think it’s interesting what the larger sample size does to the right tails of the distribution. This is good work.

Comment: I run it once again, wasn't sure I changed the plot. Regarding the distribution, indeed. I should probably compare different sample sizes  when I'll have the time.

Comment: if you qqplot (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html) one of the trends, such as "akrun" then I bet there is one point that is very different from the distribution of the rest.  The rest represent how long it takes if you run it repeatedly, but that represents what happens if you run it once.  There is an old saying: you can have 20 years of experience or you can have only one years worth of experience 20 times.

Comment: very nice!  I’m surprised by several samples being in the extreme tail. I wonder why it is that those are so much more costly. JIT might be 1 or 2 but not 20. Condition? Interrupts? Other? Thanks again for the update.

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for the thoughts. Don't know, I actually allowed it to run "freely".

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df))<nrow(df)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using the [map_lgl](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) function from the `purrr` package, which returns a logical vector and using the `[` to remove the columns with `all` NA. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5 , nas = rep(NA, 5) , vals = sample(c(1:3,NA), 5, repl = TRUE))
df
#>   id nas vals
#> 1  1  NA    2
#> 2  2  NA    3
#> 3  3  NA    3
#> 4  4  NA   NA
#> 5  5  NA    3
library(purrr)
df[!map_lgl(df, ~ all(is.na(.)))]
#>   id vals
#> 1  1    2
#> 2  2    3
#> 3  3    3
#> 4  4   NA
#> 5  5    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>