# Exclude the columns who consist of only NA's

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

My question if very much like a previous question ([Remove rows with NAs (missing values) in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)). I would like to filter my matrix in such a way that all the column with just NA's will be gone. I want to keept the column with consist of a mixture of NA's and numbers. So in the example below, I would like to get rid of the columns named *mmul* and *cfam* and keep the rest.

```
             gene hsap mmul mmus rnor cfam
1 ENSG00000208234    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 ENSG00000199674    0   NA    2    2   NA
3 ENSG00000221622    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA   NA    1   NA
5 ENSG00000207431    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 ENSG00000221312    0   NA    2    3   NA
```

I want my new matrix to look like this:

```
             gene hsap  mmus rnor 
1 ENSG00000208234    0   NA   NA  
2 ENSG00000199674    0    2    2  
3 ENSG00000221622    0   NA   NA  
4 ENSG00000207604    0   NA    1  
5 ENSG00000207431    0   NA   NA  
6 ENSG00000221312    0    2    3
```

Comment: Could try `df[colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)]`

Comment: Or similarly `df[!!colSums(!is.na(df))]`

Comment: Or `df[colSums(!is.na(df)) > 0]` ... dupes?

Comment: @docendodiscimus it the same just not golfed. You right about the dupe. Forgot to look for one.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968494

Comment: @DavidArenburg of course it is.. I'm not a big fan of `!!` golfing  (unless it's a code golfing question)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I posted the answer in dupe.  Deleted here..

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `all(is.na())`:

```
DF = data.frame(Col1 = c(NA,NA),Col2 = c(1,1));
DFOut = DF[!apply(DF,2,function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
```