# How to drop all variables/columns without content from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider that my dataset is large and more complicated (more columns and rows).

This would be a simpler set as an example:

```
A <- rep(NA,10)
B <- rep(2,10)
C <- rep(NA,10)
D <- rep('B',10)
E <- c('NA',rep('XY',9))

dat <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)

    A B  C D  E
1  NA 2 NA B NA
2  NA 2 NA B XY
3  NA 2 NA B XY
4  NA 2 NA B XY
5  NA 2 NA B XY
6  NA 2 NA B XY
7  NA 2 NA B XY
8  NA 2 NA B XY
9  NA 2 NA B XY
10 NA 2 NA B XY
```

Variable A and Variabel B do not include any data.
I would like to drop all variables from the data.frame that do include only NAs, so that the variables with content remain.
dplyr solutions are welcome, but others as well.

Comment: I'd do `Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), dat)`, but it seems there is already a topic like yours -  [How to delete columns that contain ONLY NAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968494/how-to-delete-columns-that-contain-only-nas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `colSums` + `is.na`

```
> dat[colSums(is.na(dat))!=nrow(dat)]
   B D    E
1  2 B <NA>
2  2 B   XY
3  2 B   XY
4  2 B   XY
5  2 B   XY
6  2 B   XY
7  2 B   XY
8  2 B   XY
9  2 B   XY
10 2 B   XY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with an index for variables with `NA`:

```
#Index
i1 <- apply(dat,2,function(x)length(which(is.na(x))))
i2 <- which(i1==nrow(dat))
dat <- dat[,-i2]
```

Output:

```
   B D  E
1  2 B NA
2  2 B XY
3  2 B XY
4  2 B XY
5  2 B XY
6  2 B XY
7  2 B XY
8  2 B XY
9  2 B XY
10 2 B XY
```