# Convert wide to long format in R

Tags: r, reshape2

My data has a long format similar to the one below:

```
ID Language  MotherTongue  SpokenatHome   HomeLang
1    English   English                      English
1    French                   French        
1    Polish    Polish         
2    Lebanese  Lebanese        Lebanese    Labanese
2    Arabic                    Arabbic
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
ID  Language1 Language2 Language 3  MotherTongue1  MotherTongue2  SpokenatHome1 HomeLan
1   English    French     Polish     English         Polish        French       English
2   Lebanese   Arabic                Labanese                      Arabic
```

I'm using using the melt and dcast functions of the reshape2 package, but it does not work. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

```
df<-df[,c("OEN", "Langugae","MotherTongue", "SpokenatHome", "MainHomeLanguage")]
dfl <- melt(df, id.vars=c("OEN", "Langugae"), measure.vars=c("MotherTongue", "SpokenatHome", "MainHomeLanguage"),
            variable.name="Language")

dfw <- dcast(dfl, OEN ~  Langugae , value.var="value" )
```

Comment: Please add your code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: I think your question similar wit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r but i dont know it will work for your data or no

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can try this (nonetheless it rely on `plyr` for indexing language) :

```
df <- read.table(text="ID Language
1    English
1    French
1    Spanish
1    Polish
2    English
2    French
3    Lebanese
3    Arabic", header=T)

# For creating an index of Language by ID (there is probably a better way to do this)
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, .(ID), mutate, ID2 =  1:length(ID)

# The same as above without using plyr :
df$ID2 <- unlist(tapply(X = df$ID, INDEX = df$ID, FUN = function(x) 1:length(x)))

# And use reshape for doing what you want
reshape(data = df, timevar = "ID2", v.names = "Language", idvar = "ID", direction = "wide")

#  ID Language.1 Language.2 Language.3 Language.4
#1  1    English     French    Spanish     Polish
#5  2    English     French       <NA>       <NA>
#7  3   Lebanese     Arabic       <NA>       <NA>
```

The same with your second dataset :

```
df2 <- read.table(text="ID Language  MotherTongue  SpokenatHome   HomeLang
1    English   English            NA      English
1    French       NA           French        NA
1    Polish    Polish         NA           NA
2    Lebanese  Lebanese        Lebanese    Labanese
2    Arabic       NA    NA             Arabbic", header=TRUE)

df2 <- ddply(df2, .(ID), mutate, ID2 =  1:length(ID))
reshape(data = df2, timevar = "ID2", v.names = c("Language", "MotherTongue", "SpokenatHome", "HomeLang"), idvar = "ID", direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Thanks Victorp. It works for a much smaller dataset.

Comment: Considering that it works only for a smaller dataset (100 rows) on my computer, do you think it's a good idea to split it into smaller pieces and then use rbind to combine them all together? Thanks

Comment: 27000 is not big... try to close software using RAM and load in R only the dataset you need.

Comment: I tried that. Rebooting my computer a few times, and running only Rstudio.

Comment: When I run the scripts, the CPU monitor jumps from 20% to >90%, and then it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text = '
                 ID Language
1    English
1    French
1    Spanish
1    Polish
2    English
2    French
3    Lebanese
3    Arabic')


# split by ID
sp <- tapply(df$Language, df$ID, function(x) x)
# max length
mls <- max(sapply(x, length))

# make same length
spNA <- lapply(sp, function(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  if(l == mls){
    out <- x
  } else {
    out <- c(x, rep(NA, mls-l))
  }
  return(out)
  }
)
# rbind
do.call(rbind, spNA)

# [,1]       [,2]     [,3]      [,4]    
# 1 "English"  "French" "Spanish" "Polish"
# 2 "English"  "French" NA        NA      
# 3 "Lebanese" "Arabic" NA        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `reshape2` solution.  Like the other answers, I had to add in a variable to represent the number of answer within each `ID` which I did with `ddply` from `plyr`.

```
df = read.table(text="ID Language  MotherTongue  SpokenatHome   HomeLang
1    English   English            NA      English
1    French       NA           French        NA
1    Polish    Polish         NA           NA
2    Lebanese  Lebanese        Lebanese    Labanese
2    Arabic       NA              Arabbic NA", header=TRUE)

require(reshape2)
df1 = melt(df, id.vars=c("ID"), variable.name = "type")

require(plyr)
# Add in variable for number of unique  answers per ID
df1 = ddply(df1, .(ID, type), mutate, num = 1:length(ID))
# Cast the dataset wide
df2 = dcast(df1, ID ~ type + num)
```

This gives multiple columns for each category (`Language`, `HomeLang`, etc.).  If you need to remove columns that contain all `NA`, you can do so as below (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na)).

```
df2[colSums(is.na(df2)) < nrow(df2)]
```

Comment: Great! This gives me the format that I wanted, but it does not work for the full dataset (27770 rows and 8 columns). I have to reduce it to only 100 rows. As Victorp suggested, this might be a memory issue. My machine is an i5 @ 3.1Ghz, 4GB memory and is running Window 7.  Just don't know why it takes a lot memory for this task. Thanks again for all your help