# Using R, getting a "Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name" using dplyr:select

Tags: r, dplyr, cbind

```
#use readtable to create data frames of following unzipped files below
x.train <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/train/X_train.txt")
subject.train <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/train/subject_train.txt")

y.train <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/train/y_train.txt")
x.test <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/test/X_test.txt")
subject.test <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/test/subject_test.txt")

y.test <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/test/y_test.txt")
features <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/features.txt")
activity.labels <- read.table("UCI HAR Dataset/activity_labels.txt")   



colnames(x.test) <- features[,2]
dataset_test <- cbind(subject.test,y.test,x.test)
colnames(dataset_test)[1] <- "subject"
colnames(dataset_test)[2] <- "activity"

test <- select(features, V2)

dataset_test <- select(dataset_test,subject,activity)

[1] Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
```

- features is a two column dataframe with the second columns containing
  the names for x.test
- subject.test is a single column data frame
- y.test is a single column data frame
- x.test is a wide data frame

After naming and binding these data frames I tried to use dplyr::select to select certain frames. However, I get an error returning dataset_test:

> "Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name"

However, test does not return an error and properly filters. Why is there the difference in behaviour?

The data I am using can be downloaded [online](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fprojectfiles%2FUCI%20HAR%20Dataset.zip). The data sources correspond to the variable names, except "_" are used instead of "."

```
dput

> dput(head(x.test[,1:5],2))
structure(list(V1 = c(0.25717778, 0.28602671), V2 = c(-0.02328523, 
-0.013163359), V3 = c(-0.014653762, -0.11908252), V4 = c(-0.938404, 
-0.97541469), V5 = c(-0.92009078, -0.9674579)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(subject.test,2))
structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 2L)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(y.test,2))
structure(list(V1 = c(5L, 5L)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(features,2))
structure(list(V1 = 1:2, V2 = c("tBodyAcc-mean()-X", "tBodyAcc-mean()-Y"
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should edit to add sample data for reproducibility. Use `dput` to provide some sample data. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What does `names(dataset_test)` return?

Comment: It returns:      [1] "subject"                              "tBodyAcc-mean()-X"                    "tBodyAcc-mean()-Y"                    "tBodyAcc-mean()-Z"                   
  [1] "subject"                              "tBodyAcc-mean()-X"                    "tBodyAcc-mean()-Y"                    "tBodyAcc-mean()-Z"                   
  [5] "tBodyAcc-std()-X"                     "tBodyAcc-std()-Y"                     "tBodyAcc-std()-Z"                     "tBodyAcc-mad()-X"                    
  [9] "tBodyAcc-mad()-Y" .....

Comment: This is what I expected it would return

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data using `dput`

Comment: Sure, so dput each variable?

Comment: posted dput as requested :)

Comment: I have seen the same error (with another dataset), after upgrading R lately. The data is unchanged.

Comment: I resolved the issue but don't exactly remember the issue.  If I recall, somehow the prior binding and merging led to duplicate column names.  See if there are any duplicate column names.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I think I'm looking at the same dataset as you. It's motion sensor data from a smart phone, isn't it?

The problem is exactly what the error message says! That dang set has duplicate column names. Here's how I explored it. I couldn't use your `dput` commands, so I couldn't try out your data. I'm showing my code and results. I suggest you substitute your variable, `dataset_test`, where I have `samsungData`.

Here's the error. If you just select the dataset, but don't indicate the columns, the error message identifies the duplicates.

```
select(samsungData)
```

That gave me this error, which is just what your own dplyr error was trying to tell you.

Error: Columns "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8", "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16", "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,24", "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,32", "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,40", ... must have a unique name

Then I wanted to see where that first column was duplicated. (I don't think I'll ever work well with regular expressions, but this one made me mad and I wanted to find it.)

```
has_dupe_col <- grep("fBodyAcc\\-bandsEnergy\\(\\)\\-1,8", names(samsungData))
names(samsungData)[has_dupe_col]
```

Results:

```
[1] "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8" "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8" "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8"
```

That showed me that the same column name appears in three positions. That won't play nicely in dplyr.

Then I wanted to see a frequency table for all the column names and call out the duplicates.

```
names_freq <- as.data.frame(table(names(samsungData)))
names_freq[names_freq$Freq > 1, ]
```

A bunch of them appear three times! Here are just a few.

```
                                Var1 Freq
9        fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,16    3
10       fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,24    3
11        fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8    3
```

Conclusion:

The tool (dplyr) isn't broken, the data is defective. If you want to use dplyr to select from this dataset, you're going to have to locate those duplicate column names and do something about them. Maybe you change the column name (dplyr's `mutate` will do it for you without grief). On the other hand, maybe they're supposed to be duplicated and they're there because they're a time series or some iteration of experimental observations. Maybe then what you need to do is merge those columns into one and provide another dimension (variable) to distinguish them.

That's the analysis part of data analysis. You'll have to dig into the data to see what the right answer is. Either that, or the question you're trying to answer need not even include those duplicate columns, in which case you throw them away and sleep peacefully.

Welcome to data science! At best, it's just 10% cool math and machine learning. 90% is putting on gloves and a mask and wiping up crap like this in your data.

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this same problem with a different data set. My tidyverse solution to identifying duplicate column names in the dataframe (df) was:

`tibble::enframe(names(df)) %>% count(value) %>% filter(n > 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This error is often caused by a data frame having columns with *identical names*, that should be the first thing to check. I was trying to check my own data frame with dplyr select helper functions (start_with, contains, etc.), but even those won't work, so you may need to export to a csv to check in Excel or some other program or use base functions to check for [duplicate column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142942/how-to-remove-duplicated-column-names-in-r).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to find duplicate column names using Base R would be using duplicated:

```
colnames(df)[which(duplicated(colnames(df)))]
```