# How do I remove duplicated columns from a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame containing many duplicated columns, for example:

```
df = data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=2:11)
```

Is there a function (base R or dplyr) that removes duplicated *columns* ? `unique()` removes duplicate rows.

Unlike [How to remove duplicated column names in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142942/how-to-remove-duplicated-column-names-in-r) my columns already have different names, but the values are identical.

Comment: It is actually not the duplicated answer mentioned above as here there is nothing about column names but duplicated column content which could have different names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying duplicate columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818125/identifying-duplicate-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: The answer here is better than the ones in that question @Emmanuel-Lin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is

```
df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
```

Or

```
df[!duplicated(unclass(df))]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `df <- as.data.frame(df); 
df[, !duplicated(as.list(df))]` (as `df `in the example is a matrix)

Comment: @JBGruber. If `df` is a `matrix` then you may need `!duplicated(asplit(df, 2))`

Comment: @JBGruber. Here, it is a `data.frame` because `sleep` is a `data.frame` and `cbind` will dispatch the `cbind.data.frame` based on the structure, but if the OP used `cbind(a = sleep[,1], b = sleep[,1], c = 1:20)`, then it would be a `matrix` as it is dispatching different method

Comment: Ah! `sleep` is a built in dataset! I did not know that.