# Is there a method of converting a string iterator to R code?

Tags: r, loops, casting

I am trying to calculate the mean (average) for all columns in my dataframe. I have created this code snippet

```
#Average overallDataset by label
overallDatasetLabels <- c("label","index","nr_pix","rows_with_2","cols_with_2","rows_with_3p","cols_with_3p","height","width","left2tile","right2tile","verticalness","top2tile","bottom2tile","horizontalness","nodiagnols")
library(dplyr)
avgOverallDataset <- summarise(group_by(overallDataset,label),nr_pix_avg=mean(nr_pix))
for (val in overallDatasetLabels){
  if (val %in% c("label","index","nr_pix")){
    next
  }
  avgOverallDataset<-cbind(avgOverallDataset,summarise(group_by(overallDataset,label),val=mean(val)))
}
```

When i run this code I get this error/warning:

```
50: In mean.default(val) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

And the resulting dataframe looks like this:

[image]

The reason for this is that the val variable is being treated as a string, but I need it to be treated as  "code" e.g

```
avgOverallDataset<- cbind(avgOverallDataset,summarise(group_by(overallDataset,label),avgrows_with_2=mean(rows_with_2)))
```

Would be valid.

How do I go about translating the "string" into values "in the code"?

Note: the multiple label columns can be removed using: [How to remove duplicated column names in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142942/how-to-remove-duplicated-column-names-in-r)

Comment: I think you are looking for `mean(!!sym(val))`. See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with `across` so that you don't have to calculate `mean` for multiple columns in a loop.

```
cols <- setdiff(overallDatasetLabels, c("label","index","nr_pix"))

avgOverallDataset <- overallDataset %>%
                      group_by(label) %>%
                      summarise(across(all_of(cols), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```