# Select columns that don't contain any NA value in R

Tags: r

How to select columns that don't contain any `NA` values in R? As long as a column contains at least one `NA`, I want to exclude it. What's the best way to do it? I am trying to use `sum(is.na(x))` to achieve this, but haven't been successful.

Also, another R question. Is it possible to use commands to exclude columns that contain all same values? For example,

```
  column1  column2
row1   a        b  
row2   a        c
row3   a        c
```

My purpose is to exclude `column1` from my matrix so the final result is:

```
   column2
row1   b  
row2   c
row3   c
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na/12614723#12614723 and modify appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na/12614723#12614723) deals with the case where ALL values are NA

For a matrix, you can use `colSums(is.na(x)` to find out which columns contain `NA` values

given a matrix `x`

```
x[, !colSums(is.na(x)), drop = FALSE]
```

will subset appropriately.

For a `data.frame`, it will be more efficient to use `lapply` or `sapply` and the function `anyNA`

```
xdf[, sapply(xdf, Negate(anyNA)), drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, could do

```
new.df <- df[, colSums(is.na(df)) == 0 ]
```

this way lets you subset based on the number of NA values in the columns.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

Also if 'mat1' is the matrix:

```
indx <- unique(which(is.na(mat1), arr.ind=TRUE)[,2])
subset(mat1, select=-indx)
```