# removing columns with NA values only

Tags: r

I am using this command to remove the columns where all the values are NA.

```
testing5 <- subset(testing4,
                   select = -c(kurtosis_picth_belt, skewness_roll_belt, 
                   skewness_roll_belt.1, min_yaw_belt, amplitude_yaw_belt, 
                   kurtosis_roll_arm, kurtosis_picth_arm, kurtosis_yaw_arm, 
                   skewness_roll_arm, skewness_pitch_arm, kurtosis_picth_dumbbell, 
                   skewness_roll_dumbbell, skewness_pitch_dumbbell, min_yaw_dumbbell, 
                   kurtosis_roll_forearm, kurtosis_picth_forearm, skewness_roll_forearm, 
                   skewness_pitch_forearm))
```

Is there a shorter (programmitic) method?

Thanks and Regards,
Partha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tidyverse approach would look like this (also using @Rich Scriven data):

```
d %>% select_if(~any(!is.na(.)))
#    x
# 1 NA
# 2  3
# 3 NA
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the columns that contain all `NA` values with e.g.

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(NA, 3, NA), y = rep(NA, 3))
#    x  y
# 1 NA NA
# 2  3 NA
# 3 NA NA

d[!sapply(d, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
#    x
# 1 NA
# 2  3
# 3 NA
```

On your data, this would be

```
testing4[!sapply(testing4, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
```

Comment: (+1) for the safer solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way (a bit more vectorized) using @Richards data

```
d[!is.nan(colMeans(d, na.rm = TRUE))]
#    x
# 1 NA
# 2  3
# 3 NA
```

Comment: On that road, perhaps something like `d[colSums(is.na(d)) < nrow(d)]` could be clearer?

Comment: @alexis_laz, brilliant suggestion as usual