# Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA, NULL or empty

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some of the values are NULL or Empty. I would like to **remove** these **columns** in which **all values** are **NULL** or **empty**.
Columns should be removed from the dataframe, do not hidden only.

My head(df) looks like data=

```
  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3   VAR4  VAR5  VAR6  VAR7
1  2R+          52   1.05     0     0    30
2  2R+         169   1.02     0     0    40
3  2R+          83     NA     0     0    40
4  2R+          98   1.16     0     0    40
5  2R+         154   1.11     0     0    40
6  2R+         111     NA     0     0    15
```

The dataframe contains more than 200 variables, variables are empty and zero values do not occur sequentially.

I tried to estimate the average Col and select the column is Null or empty, by analogy with the removal of "NA" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643939/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-all-values-are-na)), but it does not work.

```
df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df))<nrow(df)]
```

I got an error : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Can anyone give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput(head(myDf, 20))`.

Comment: Do you want to remove columns that have all 0s?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove all columns in which all values are NA, NULL or empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !(all(x=="")), df)
#   Var1 Var3
#1  2R+   52
#2  2R+  169
#3  2R+   83
#4  2R+   98
#5  2R+   NA
#6  2R+  111
#7  2R+   94
#8  2R+  116
#9  2R+   86
```

NOTE: It should also work if all the elements are NA for a particular column

```
df$Var3 <- NA
Filter(function(x) !(all(x=="")), df)
#   Var1
#1  2R+
#2  2R+
#3  2R+
#4  2R+
#5  2R+
#6  2R+
#7  2R+
#8  2R+
#9  2R+
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, if we need to remove the columns with only 0 values, then change the code to

```
Filter(function(x) !(all(x==""|x==0)), df2)
#    VAR1 VAR3 VAR4 VAR7
#1  2R+   52 1.05   30
#2  2R+  169 1.02   40
#3  2R+   83   NA   40
#4  2R+   98 1.16   40
#5  2R+  154 1.11   40
#6  2R+  111   NA   15
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(VAR1 = c("2R+", "2R+", "2R+", "2R+", "2R+", "2R+"
), VAR2 = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), VAR3 = c(52L, 169L, 83L, 
98L, 154L, 111L), VAR4 = c(1.05, 1.02, NA, 1.16, 1.11, NA), VAR5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VAR6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VAR7 = c(30L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 15L)), .Names = c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", 
"VAR4", "VAR5", "VAR6", "VAR7"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ok!, I have done! ;)